# Error while generating pdf in Joomla 3.0

Tags: pdf, joomla, dompdf

I have created my custom component.
Every thing is working fine.
but when I am appending format=pdf in URL Joomla shows error

> "0 - Invalid controller: name='xxxxxxxx', format='pdf'"

If I am adding format=html then its working fine.

I have followed this article for pdf generating.
[joomla pdf](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your `controller.php` file in your custom component's XML manifest file? If you don't have it there, then this is most likely the cause of your problem.